# hide a field in webform components

Tags: webforms

I want to hide the field `"form key"` in all of the webform components.
I tried doing it with `"*hook_form_alter*"` and with "*[#access] = false*" but I can't succeed in this.
I also tried to use `"*hook_webform_component_load*"`.

But in all of those, i can't understand exactly what I need to do to hide the form key field in all of the components in all of the webforms. I can't even hide one component's "form key" field. I don't understand which is the field that i need to modify.

p.s - im using form_builder too.

I'm doing something wrong.

any help will be appreciated.
thanks, alexandra.

Comment: Can't you just use hidden component of webform.?

Comment: No, I wanna hide it from the admin interface. not from the view. I don't want users that have access to the admin panel to be able to edit it or see it.

Answer (score 1):

The [webform_civicrm](https://drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) module does this (actually it disables it rather than hiding it)

You can see the [relevant code here](https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/blob/7.x-4.11/includes/wf_crm_admin_component.inc#L50) (note this function runs in the context of hook_form_alter).

You could hide it by doing something similar but setting `$form['form_key']['#type'] = 'hidden';`

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no experience with the [Webform Locked Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_locked_fields) module myself, it sounds like the module does exactly what you are asking for (so no custom code needed).

> With this module you can lock fields in a webform so that those fields
>   cannot be deleted or modified except by administrators with
>   appropriate permissions.
>
> Users who have the "administer webform locked fields" permission will
>   see a checkbox titled "Webform creator can modify" when they edit a
>   webform component. If that box is unchecked, the component can only be
>   modified or deleted by users who have the the "administer webform
>   locked fields" permission. Other users who have webform creation
>   permission will be taken to a page that says "Not allowed" if they
>   attempt to edit or delete that component.